# Wiremock for real time requests

Tags: wiremock

I'm trying to use wire mock for mocking one of my third party service. However, unlike in most of the use cases, I need this for real time requests for one of my environment. The calls will not be coming from unit/integration tests.

To support this use case , I need my wire mock server to be always up and running unlike other use cases where wire mock server comes up only when the tests are executed.
Where do I start and configure the wire mock server for my use case? Is Application.java the right place? 
Also, where do I define the stubs?

Answer (score 1):

You can run the WireMock server in standalone, and host it wherever you have access. The stubs are defined under the `/mappings` directory from where the WireMock standalone is executed. More information on running in [standalone can be found here.](http://wiremock.org/docs/running-standalone/)

You could also just have the WireMock server configured as a project and have it deployed through whatever means necessary or available. Sorry if that is a little open-ended as an answer, but without knowing the specifics of what is available, there isn't much direction to go in.

Additionally, the maintainer of WireMock offers a paid service that will host the mock server for you, called [MockLab](https://www.mocklab.io/docs/getting-started/)